# How can you change form button appearance?

Tags: css

I am wondering if it is possible to change the appearance of form buttons. Mostly the Height, Width etc. but also color if possible without having to create an image for it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets

Comment: http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/css/mouseover/beispiel1.htm

Comment: Of course! Search for articles and blog posts about styling form buttons / elements with CSS. This one comes up for me, as an example: http://blog.formstack.com/2010/customize-form-buttons-with-css/

Comment: I did search but all I found was putting images instead of a normal button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can. Buttons can be styled like more other elements on the page via CSS. For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hs95X/

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Button1" class="c1" />
       <input type="button" value="Button2" class="c2" />
       <input type="button" value="Button3" class="c3" />
</form>

.c1 {
    background-color: #cc0000;
}
.c2 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #cc0000;
}
.c3 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #cc0000;
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
}
```

You should see a `Button1` with a red background, `Button2` with white text on red and `Button3` with a larger size. You can do much more than that but that's a start.

Comment: Ok so you just use classes like any other element then.

Comment: Yes! Some elements like ``input type="file"`` are harder to style (or at least used to be, last time I checked) but regular buttons are fine.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp

Click the link and learn the tutorial you will get everything you need.

You can change the shape of the button by change the background colour, board, corner radius.

```
<style>
button{
background: #444;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #333;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: [No.](http://www.w3fools.com/) (FWIW, I didn't downvote, but this is still important.)  Read the link in my comment.  w3schools should not be considered when needing a source to learn from.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I removed my downvote. I downvoted because it was a link only answer, with a copy-paste from the website menu, and the link points to CSS3 Animations, which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @MathieuImbert no worries :) just try to help here